# Does the installed Grafana plugins make external calls?

Tags: azure

From the Grafana forum, I came to know that the installed Third-party plugins may make external calls, Also, they recommend to configure the network to traffic that we approve. In my case, I have installed the Grafana instance behind an Azure Application Gateway.

https://community.grafana.com/t/how-secure-are-community-built-grafana-plugins/33959

so my questions are

1. How to confirm from my Grafana instance the external calls are allowed or not? can we test this with any Linux commands?
2. My Grafana instance is running behind an Appgateway so the instance doesn't have a public IP. still, external calls are allowed from my instance?
3. How can I secure my Grafana not to make any external calls?

Thanks

Comment: Please can someone answer my question?